# Controlling tab space in a <pre> using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to specify how many pixels, etc. the tab space occupies in a `<pre>` using CSS?

for example, say i have a piece of code appearing in a `<pre>` on a web page:

```
function Image()
{
    this.Write = function()
    {
        document.write(this.ToString());
        return this;
    };
    ...
}
Image.prototype = new Properties();
...
```

is it possible to specify a different amount of space the tab indents the line using CSS?

If not, is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From CSS 2.1, [§ 16.6.1 The 'white-space' processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model):

> All tabs (U+0009) are rendered as a horizontal shift that lines up the start edge of the next glyph with the next tab stop. Tab stops occur at points that are multiples of 8 times the width of a space (U+0020) rendered in the block's font from the block's starting content edge.

CSS3 Text says basically the same thing.

From HTML 4.01 [§ 9.3.4 Preformatted text: The PRE element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4)

> The horizontal tab character (decimal 9 in [ISO10646] and [ISO88591] ) is usually interpreted by visual user agents as the smallest non-zero number of spaces necessary to line characters up along tab stops that are every 8 characters. We strongly discourage using horizontal tabs in preformatted text since it is common practice, when editing, to set the tab-spacing to other values, leading to misaligned documents.

If you're concerned with leading tabs, it's a simple matter to replace them with spaces.

```
/* repeat implemented using Russian Peasant multiplication */
String.prototype.repeat = function (n) {
    if (n<1) return '';
    var accum = '', c=this;
    for (; n; n >>=1) {
        if (1&n) accum += c;
        c += c;
    }
    return accum;
}
String.prototype.untabify = function(tabWidth) {
    tabWidth = tabWidth || 4;
    return this.replace(/^\t+/gm, function(tabs) { return ' '.repeat(tabWidth * tabs.length)} );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, replacing with spaces is probably a good thing to do :)

Answer (score 5):

While the above discussion provides some historical background, times have changed, and more relevant information and possible solutions can be found here: [Specifying Tab-Width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667200/specifying-tab-width)

attn admin: possible duplicate of ref'ed question.