# Tab width CSS property

Tags: css, tabs, cross-browser

Do the WebKit and Microsoft browsers support any method of specifying tab width like Firefox and Opera do using their `-moz-tab-size` and `-o-tab-size` properties?

For example, I want the tabs in my `<textarea>` to have a width of 4 spaces:

```
textarea {
    -moz-tab-size: 4;
    -o-tab-size: 4;
    /* How would I do this in Chrome, Safari, and IE? */
}
```

### [Update:]

I created a `tab-size` polyfill ([Demo](http://jsbin.com/ozohec/edit#javascript,html,live)):

```
<script> // tab-size polyfill
var codeElements = document.getElementsByTagName('code'), // Applies to all code elements. Adjust to your needs.
codeElementCount = codeElements.length,
e = d.createElement('i');

if(e.style.tabSize !== '' && e.style.mozTabSize !== '' && e.style.oTabSize !== '') {
    for(var i = 0; i < codeElementCount; i++) {
        codeElements[i].innerHTML = codeElements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\t/g,'<span class="tab">&#9;</span>');
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.tab {
    width: 2.5em; /* adjust to your needs */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

**Note:** This wont work on `<textarea>`s, but only on element's that can contain other elements. If the browser does support `tab-size` it'll use that instead.

Comment: Relevant specification for the `tab-size` property: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#tab-size

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock! What support does that property have in Chrome, Safari, and IE?

Comment: None, so far. I've posted an answer.

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52994 - seems this has now been fixed in WebKit

Comment: I recently created this jQuery plugin to solve this problem on one of my sites. https://github.com/davestewart/jquery-plugins/tree/master/tabSize It uses the CSS3 property tab-size if available, but if not, it *correctly* converts tabs to spaces, including those tabs which do not take up a whole tab width, aka columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`tab-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#tab-size) is currently only implemented by Firefox and Opera using your given vendor prefixes.

For WebKit, [there's a bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52994) requesting that the property be implemented. I believe work has already started on it, as can be seen in the comments on that report.

For IE, well, I can't find anything about an `-ms-tab-size` or `tab-size` implementation in IE9 or IE10. I suppose the IE team has been none the wiser.

Comment: The `tab-size` property seems to be supported by Chrome now.

Comment: @BoltClock So how twitter bootstrap did that in their code examples? They didn't use any things that i have seen, they didn't use tab-size css property, they didn't replace it with spaces, or any spans with properly width.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a [similar question on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667200/specifying-tab-width), but it doesn't really quite answer that quite right. It does, however reference that <del>apparently [tab stops do exist in CSS](http://www.w3.org/People/howcome/t/970224HTMLERB-CSS/WD-tabs-970117.html)</del>, though I can't imagine the browser support is all that great on it.

[Searching on google](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+tab-size+property+textarea) for it brings up little to no information on the subject<del>, further leading me to believe that it isn't very well-implemented, or used</del>. Hope that helps.

#### EDIT

The W3C link does mention tab-stops, but it was only a working draft - a proposal, and was not implemented.

Comment: Tab stops didn't exist in CSS. That was just a working draft from more than 14 years ago.

Comment: **My** bad, I just found that they resurfaced in the [CSS3 working drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#tab-size) as `tab-size` (and, as the OP shows, Firefox and Opera have their own implementations). They didn't make it to CSS1 or CSS2, but they may have a chance in CSS3.

Comment: Found, then forgotten... Sigh. One day we will have tabs!