# How can I change the default tab size in highlighted code in Jekyll 3.0?

Tags: tabs, format, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

If I did:

```
{% highlight C %}
    .... code
{% endhighlight %}
```

For any tab I use between the highlighted C, I'd like the tab size to be 2 rather than 4. Doing `{% highlight C tabsize=2 %}` doesn't seem to work in Jekyll 3.

The answers I have seen on SO seem to work for older versions, but not recent versions.

Comment: By "older" you appear to mean the [pygments code formatter](http://pygments.org/docs/filters/) and it's option, that is not around in the now default [„rouge“ highlighter](https://github.com/jneen/rouge#full-options).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible from Jekyll itself, but you can accomplish this with CSS using the [`tab-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size) attribute:

```
pre {
    tab-size: 2;
}
```

Comment: Strangely, [it's said to not work on IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-tabsize)... (can't verify right now, but also [confirmed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6754883/444255))

Comment: You saved my day!